# Re-create primary key in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I previously converted one of my tables' id column to bigint, and populated it with bigint values. I'm now regretting that as I can't seem to update values via ActiveRecord [without runnning into RangeErrors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41838958/rangeerror-when-using-bigint-ids-in-rails).

I'd like to convert the id column back to the standard integer type, and clear out the existing values and populate it with auto-incremented integer values.

I don't have any foreign keys / relations I need to worry about.

Is there a straightforward way to do this via a Rails migration (Rails 4 / Postgres)?

**The prior migration:**

```
class ConvertWidgetPkToBigint < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :widgets, :id, :bigint
  end
end
```

**Current schema.rb:**

```
create_table "widgets", id: :bigserial, force: :cascade do |t|
...
end
```

Comment: I don't think there's a straightforward way (it's not a common thing to do). Can you drop the column and then add it again?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
class RecreatePrimaryKey < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    execute "UPDATE widgets SET id = DEFAULT"
    change_column :widgets, :id, :integer
  end
end
```

Basically it re-populates the column with auto-increment values, and then converts the column back to type integer.